Turkish İ lowercasing as two characters: is this a bug in Python?
I found out that the Turkish/Azeri LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE (U+0130, İ) is the only character that gets converted into two when I use the .lower() method in Python.
my_str = "İZMİR FUßBALL CAFÉ"
print(my_str.lower())

>>> i̇zmi̇r fußball café

See the double dot in i̇? This is the regular Latin small i and a COMBINING DOT ABOVE (U+0307). I find it quite surprising, as I would expect the output to be just i (without the combining dot).
This is important for me, since this causes the lengths of the original and the lowercased strings to be different. The way I understand it is that it should be the .casefold() method that interferes with the string length and replaces more characters for one (e.g. ß > ss). And .lower() should leave the length intact.
You can see below that the lengths are different and, consequently, the characters don't match.
print(len(my_str))
print(len(my_str.lower()))

>>> 18
>>> 20

from itertools import zip_longest
for a, b in zip_longest(my_str, my_str.lower()):
    print(a, "   ", b)
    
>>> İ     i
>>> Z     ̇
>>> M     z
>>> İ     m
>>> R     i
>>>       ̇
>>> F     r
>>> U      
>>> ß     f
>>> B     u
>>> A     ß
>>> L     b
>>> L     a
>>>       l
>>> C     l
>>> A      
>>> F     c
>>> É     a
>>> None     f
>>> None     é

Here I checked that it is indeed the ONLY character that behaves in this weird way when lowercased (based on a script from this answer).
import sys
import unicodedata as ud

print("Unicode version:", ud.unidata_version, "\n")
total = 0
for codepoint in map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode)):
    lower = codepoint.lower()
    if len(lower) > 1:
        total += 1
        for conversion, converted in zip(
            ("orig", "lower"),
            (codepoint, lower)
        ):
            print(conversion, [ud.name(cp) for cp in converted], converted)
        print()
print("Total chars converted to more than one char when lowercased:", total)

>>> Unicode version: 13.0.0 
>>> 
>>> orig ['LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE'] İ
>>> lower ['LATIN SMALL LETTER I', 'COMBINING DOT ABOVE'] i̇
>>> 
>>> Total chars converted to more than one char when lowercased: 1


I don't understand the logic behind this substitution. This seems like something implemented so you can reconstruct an İ if there is an i̇ substring in a string.lower(). But when there's an a, you can't tell if the original string had an A or an a, so why is there an exception for this character?
My original problem was the umatching lengths of the original and lowercase strings, but since I found the culprit in my data (which is the letter İ), I already have a solution (either replacing i̇ to i in the target string or customizing the .lower() method). But I am still curious why is it like that in Python in the first place, and that's why I'm asking the question.

The problem is that Python uses a generic (universal) algorithm, but sorting and casing depends on language. You may need better functions (which take language as parameter), so "İ" may fails (it is a well known problem). But your case is about decomposition of characters. That is fine: you should never assume that a character will be transformed in a single character, or also the contrary, you may need two characters to transform in one. Unicode has many combining characters. (note: maybe you can later normalize and compose them)

I thought that maybe this universal (language-agnostic) algorithm would make more sense if it converted always 1 char > 1 char. But I think that now, after a moment, I understand why it does this. Because jumping back on forth from lowercase to uppercase gives as consistently İ > i̇ > İ > i̇... (just like A > a > A...) and not İ > i > I(!) ) > i > I. This answers my question. Not a bug

Unicode has not a strict concept of characters, in fact (and for initial design), they have "combining characters". Note: MacOS prefers to decompose characters. In any case, e.g. German ß uppercase is SS

Giacomo, thanks for your input!

Unicode defines both simple and full case mapping. simple case mapping is always 1 to 1,  if there isn't a 1 to 1 mappng available character remains unchanged. Unicode also has language insensitive mapping, and language sensitive mapping. Python implements full language insensitive case mapping. Full case mapping is asymmetric.

@adamsierakowski, language insensitive mappings would give you: İ (U+0130) > i̇ (U+0069 U+0307) > İ (U+0049 U+0307) > i̇ (U+0069 U+0307).
